# Erro ao tentar passar uma lista da controller para view ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Boa dia pessoal,

Sou novo no desenvolvimento, e estou tendo problemas em passar uma lista de uma query da controller para uma view.
Dei uma pesquisada e todas as formas que encontrei não ajudaram muito, se alguém puder me ajudar nessa ficarei grato.

Segue controller:

```
namespace DinheiroControlado.Controllers
{
public class RelatorioController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Relatorio/
    private DinheiroControladoBD db2 = new DinheiroControladoBD();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var cookie = DinheiroControlado.Repositorios.RepositoriosUsuarios.VerificaSeOUsuarioEstaLogado();
        var dados = (from d in db2.Movimentacoes
                    join c in db2.Categorias on d.IDCategoria equals c.IDCategoria
                    where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario
                    group d by c.Descricao into g
                    select new { Categoria = g.Key, Valor = g.Sum(d => d.Valor)}).Take(5);

        ViewBag.grafico = dados;

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Segue View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Layout2.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
  <tbody>
    @{foreach (var item in ViewBag.grafico)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Categoria
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Valor
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Erro que está ocorrendo:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'. 'object' não contém uma definição para    'Categoria' Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' não contém uma definição para 'Categoria'

Erro de Origem: 

Linha 11: <tr>
Linha 12: <td>
Linha 13: @item.Categoria
Linha 14: </td>
Linha 15: <td> 
Arquivo de Origem:    c:\TCC\C#\DinheiroControlado\DinheiroControlado\Views\Relatorio\Index.cshtml    Linha: 13 

Rastreamento de Pilha:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu aconselho você a fazer o seguinte:

- Crie uma classe para encapsular as informações do gráfico
- Adicione um modelo da dados para esta view

Você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
//Classe para o encapsulamento
public class ItemGrafico
{
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}

//Altere o select para new ItemGrafico
var dados = (from d in db2.Movimentacoes
                join c in db2.Categorias on d.IDCategoria equals c.IDCategoria
                where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario
                group d by c.Descricao into g
                select new ItemGrafico { Categoria = g.Key, Valor = g.Sum(d => d.Valor)}).Take(5);
```

Na sua action no controller faça o seguinte:

```
return View("NomeDaSuaView", dados);
```

E por fim na sua view faça as seguintes alterações:

Na primeira linha:

```
@model IEnumerable<seu.namespace.completo.ItemGrafico>
```

e no `foreach` altere para fica assim:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           @item.Categoria
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.Valor
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Fazendo essas alterações você deve conseguir fazer o que deseja sem mais problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara!!! era isso que precisava!! deu certo!